# Setup Solaris 11 name server to manage domain

Tags: dns, solaris, bind

How do i setup my nameserver to manage a domain and then include a zone for it.

I have never managed domains before and i hope somebody could point me the right direction.

Do i have to setup the file ? if so how? :

```
resolv.conf
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: maybe ask on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

`resolv.conf` is for DNS clients; My understanding is you want to setup a DNS server with which the setup file is `/etc/named.conf`.

Have a look at the [Solaris 11 DNS administration documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1455/dnsref-31.html) for details: